# Unique Solution to an Integral Equation

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a bdd open set in $R^n$ and let K(x,y) be a Lebesgue measurable function on the product space $X$ x $X$ such that $$\int_X \int_X |K(x,y)|^2dx dy $$ is finite.
Let f(x) be a function in $L^2(X)$. Consider the integral equation, $$u(x)=f(x) + \lambda\int_XK(x,y)u(y)dy$$ where $\lambda$ is a complex number. Prove that there exists a small positive number $\lambda_0$ such that, for any complex number $\lambda$, with $|\lambda|<\lambda_0$, there exists a unique solution $u(x)$ to the integral equation above.

I have never dealt with integral equations, and we haven't talked about them in class thus far. This is a homework problem that i have no idea about, but still needs to get done. If anyone could give a proof, I will sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda_0$ be a positive number such that $\lambda_0 \|K\|_{L^2(X \times X)}\sqrt{|X|} < 1$, where $|X|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $X$. Let $|\lambda| < \lambda_0$ and define a mapping

$$\Phi : L^2(X) \to L^2(X)$$

by the equation

$$\Phi(u)(x) = f(x) + \lambda\int_X K(x,y)u(y)\, dy \quad (x\in X).$$

For all $u, v \in L^2(X)$,

$$|\Phi(u)(x) - \Phi(v)(x)| \le |\lambda| \int_X |K(x,y)||u(y) - v(y)|\, dy \le \|K\|_{L^2(X \times X)} \|u - v\|_{L^2(X)}$$

for all $x \in X$. Hence, for all $u,v \in L^2(X)$,

$$\|\Phi(u) - \Phi(v)\|_{L^2(X)} \le |\lambda| \|K\|_{L^2(X)} \sqrt{|X|}\|u - v\|_{L^2(X)} \le C\|u - v\|_{L^2(X)},$$

where $C = \lambda_0 \|K\|_{L^2(X)}\sqrt{|X|}$. By assumption, $C \in (0,1)$, so $\Phi$ is a contraction mapping on the complete metric space $L^2(X)$. By Banach's contraction principle, $\Phi$ has a unique fixed point. This means there is a unique solution to the integral equation above.